# Changing the date format when writing out as a CSV

Tags: python, csv, datetime

I'm reading data from a database that has the date format as YYYY-MM-DD. However, when I write this out to a CSV, the date changes to MM/DD/YYYY. I'd like to stop this from happening.
I'd like to add in a line using `datetime` to enforce my preferred format. Here's what I've tried.

```
# write out
for line in reader:
    # format the date to YYYY-MM-DD (line 26 is date column)
    line[26] = datetime.datetime.strptime(line[26], "%Y-%m-%d")
    # write out 
    csv_out.writerow(line)
```

However I get the following error from this:

```
line[26] = line[26].datetime.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'datetime'
```

How do I properly format the date?

EDIT: Note `line[26]` is a str format.

Comment: What is the type of `line[26]`? If it's a `datetime` object, just do `line[26].strftime`. If it's a `str`, you need to use `datetime.strptime` to parse it to a `datetime` first, and then use `strftime` on that. (Note: `datetime` is both the name of the module and of a type contained in that module.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried doing `line[26] = datetime.datetime.strptime(line[26], "%Y-%m-%d").strftime("%Y-%m-%d")`

For example:

```py
line = '2019-05-12'
print(type(line))

>>> <class 'str'>

line = datetime.datetime.strptime(line, "%Y-%m-%d").strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
print(line)

>>> 2019-12-05
```